# Symfony Translatable Enum

Tags: php, symfony, enums, symfony-translator

My supplier entity has enum property notifyType. Any idea how translate the enum this way?

```
{{ supplier.notifyType|trans }}
```

Unfortunately, use __toString method in Enum is not possible.

```php
// error - Enum may not include __toString
public function __toString(): string
{
    return 'supplier.notify.'.$this->name;
}
```

Then I just tried this:

```php
use Symfony\Contracts\Translation\TranslatableInterface;
use Symfony\Contracts\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

enum NotifyType: int implements TranslatableInterface
{
    case EMAIL = 1;
    case WEBHOOK = 2;
    case PUNCH_OUT = 4;

    public function trans(TranslatorInterface $translator, string $locale = null): string
    {
        return $translator->trans('supplier.notify.'.$this->name, locale: $locale);
    }
}
```

But it's not possible pass translatable object to trans method. String only accepted.

```php
$this->translator->trans(NotifyType::EMAIL); // error: must be of type string
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR : `NotifyType::EMAIL->trans($this->translator)`

---

Your Enum **is correct and should works like that** thanks to `TranslatableInterface` implementation.

The only problem that I can find with that is the "auto discover" by `translation:extract` symfony's command will not correctly works, since your **translations are dynamics**.

You should avoid using concatenated `trans id` and use `match` expression instead
(assuming you are in `PHP >= 8.1` because of the enum problem) :

```php
enum NotifyType: int implements TranslatableInterface
{
    case EMAIL = 1;
    case WEBHOOK = 2;
    case PUNCH_OUT = 4;

    public function trans(TranslatorInterface $translator, string $locale = null): string
    {
        return match ($this) {
            self::EMAIL     => $translator->trans('supplier.notify.email', locale: $locale),
            self::WEBHOOK   => $translator->trans('supplier.notify.webhook', locale: $locale),
            self::PUNCH_OUT => $translator->trans('supplier.notify.punch_out', locale: $locale),
        };
    }
}
```

#### PHP usage

`NotifyType::EMAIL->trans($this->translator)`

#### Twig usage

`{{ supplier.notifyType | trans }}`

But definitely not like that :

- `{{ supplier.notifyType.value | trans }}` => wrong
- `{{ supplier.notifyType.name | trans }}` => wrong

---

> Edit: Added `$locale` to trans() function calls, thx @jared-farrish

Comment: Shouldn't `$locale` be used in the `->trans()` call?

Answer (score 0):

The `|trans` simply calls `TranslatorExtension`'s `trans` function with the value it filters as a parameter. It only accepts the following types: `string|\Stringable|TranslatableInterface|null`

So then you have 2 ***(Edit: 3)*** solutions:

1. Make your own `|trans` filter that overrides the one from `TranslatorExtension` (not ideal IMO)
2. Create your own filters specifically for Enums.

**EDIT**
There is a third and simpler solution: add a public function (for example `getTransString`) in your Enum that returns `'supplier.notify.'. $this->name` and do this in twig: `{{ supplier.notifyType.getTransString|trans }}`

Here's a very simple example of the second solution that I tried and worked as expected:

```
class EnumTranslationService
{
    public function __construct(private readonly TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
    }

    public function translateNotifyType(NotifyType $notifyType): string
    {
        return $this->translator->trans('supplier.notify.' . $notifyType->name);
    }
}
```

AppExtension:

```
class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function getFilters(): array
    {
        return [
            new TwigFilter('transNotifyType', [EnumTranslationService::class, 'translateNotifyType'])
        ];
    }
}
```

Twig:

```
{{ supplier.notifyType|transNotifyType }}
```